# How does WordPress generate a comment website preview?

Tags: comments

In the WordPress comment que, hovering over the URL of a comment generates a preview of the website. How does WordPress handle this and does this generate a hit, or 'visit' to that website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress runs a service to generate screenshots. You can get any website screenshot like this.

```
http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http://www.google.com?w=400&h=300
```

And yes, it records as a hit on website and will be logged.